# Expression: string iterator not dereferencable while using boost regex

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, boost, boost-regex

I want to recover all the links from a page, while executing this code I get:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library
>
> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\Users\Gandalf\Desktop\proxy\Debug\Proxy.exe File:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring Line:
>   78
>
> Expression: string iterator not dereferencable
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)
>
> Abort   Retry   Ignore

```
void Deltacore::Client::get_links() {
boost::smatch matches;
boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
boost::regex URL_REGEX("^<a[^>]*(http://[^\"]*)[^>]*>([ 0-9a-zA-Z]+)</a>$");

if(!response.empty()) {

    std::string::const_iterator alfa = this->response.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator omega   = this->response.end();

    while (boost::regex_search(alfa, omega, matches, URL_REGEX))
    {
        std::cout << matches[0];
        //if(std::find(this->Links.begin(), this->Links.end(), matches[0]) != this->Links.end()) {
            this->Links.push_back(matches[0]);
        //}
        alfa = matches[0].second;
    }
}
}
```

Any Ideea?

Added more code:

```
        Deltacore::Client client;
    client.get_url(target);
    client.get_links();

            boost::property_tree::ptree props;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < client.Links.size(); i++)
                props.push_back(std::make_pair(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i), client.Links.at(i)));

            std::stringstream ss;
            boost::property_tree::write_json(ss, props, false);

            boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                boost::asio::buffer(ss.str(), ss.str().length()),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just try with the std::string::iterator instead of const_iterator.

Comment: @Wug It's in the C++ basic includes, I'm pretty sure the error is in my code.

Comment: @Mahesh boost::regex_search for some reason forces me to use std::string::const_iterator

Comment: Maybe it wants end() - 1 or something.  That's an assertion right?  (It says it is.)  What is the value of the string before you get the iterators?

Comment: this->response is the full HTML output of a page (I get it using cURL).

Comment: Is `matches[0].second` guaranteed to be an iterator into the original string? You should be able to get the debugger to tell you where in your code the asserting call is happening, btw.

Comment: I added the actual use of the function. Since the debugger isn't too helpful. The error may be triggered from there.

Comment: What's strange is that the crash is random. If I execute the code again it works.

Comment: @Claudiu : That's not "weird", sounds like vanilla [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). What is the actual data in `response` when the regex is run?

Comment: if(!response.empty()) {
is a silly coders mistake it's this->response

Comment: `this->` is usually optional.  Using or omitting it is a style decision, not a mistake.

Comment: It's seems the error triggers after executing boost::asio::async_write. It succesfuly sends the string and then crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
boost::asio::buffer(ss.str(), ss.str().length())
```

`str()` returns a *temporary* `std::string` object, so you are actually invalidating the buffer as soon as you create it – vanilla UB, as I commented. ;-]

Token [documentation citation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload30.html):

> The buffer is invalidated by any non-const operation called on the given string object.

Of course, destroying the string qualifies as a non-const operation.

Comment: That actually fixed it. Thank you. It's 2 AM and I'm writing bad code :/

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the lecture on using regex to parse HTML (and how you really shouldn't...), your regex doesn't look like it will work like you intend. This is yours:

```
"^<a[^>]*(http://[^\"]*)[^>]*>([ 0-9a-zA-Z]+)</a>$"
```

The first character class will be greedy and eat up your http and following parts. You want to add a question mark to make it not greedy.

```
"^<a[^>]*?(http://[^\"]*)[^>]*>([ 0-9a-zA-Z]+)</a>$"
```

This might or might not be related to the exception.